# Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I need a way of displaying 3 cells of data.
For example

```
Cell 1            Cell 2          Cell 3    

20                 140            Lee
12                 110            Kerrie
```

Whenever anyone's name is input in cell 3 I need a separate spreadsheet to display the name (cell 3) and the information in cells 1 & 2 (the information in cells 1 & 2 will always be different).

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: anyone's name input from where?

Comment: names are input at random and can be input more than once.

Comment: @Lost- my question is input from where, is a macro causing this spreadsheet to be populated from another app, is it imported from a webpage, is the data already in the spreadsheet and you just want to change it to a new one based on the conditions?

Comment: o sorry no the names are inout manually. Its probably something really simlpe but im not to familiar with excel

Comment: "Separate spreadsheet" - is this a new worksheet or workbook?
Where in this new sheet should the text in columns A, B & C go?

Comment: @Lost- could you show an example of what you want, because I still don't understand what the expected outcome is

Comment: Maybe if you could explain the purpose of what you're doing we'd have a better answer. Are you sure Excel is the right tool for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

From your question it's unclear whether you're talking about a person's name input into a single cell (e.g., "C3") or somewhere in a given column (e.g., "C:C").

In the former case you can easily use Guiness's suggestion; or you can even more easily write a formula like this to concatenate the values in Cells 1 through 3 (supposing the worksheet is called "Sheet1"):

```
="Name = "&Sheet1!C3&": Cell1 = "&Sheet1!A3&", Cell2 = "&Sheet1!B3
```

(This is based on Cells 1 through 3 in your example being in columns A through C, and in row 3.)

On the other hand, if you're talking about the latter case and you want to run some VBA code whenever a new name is ADDED to column C, you can use the Worksheet_Change VBA function. If this is the case, edit the question to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Say you have Excel workbook 1 called Book1.xls. Open that workbook and type the following in the first three rows and across first three columns
   Row 1 - cell1   cell2   cell3
   Row 2 - 20  12  Jee
   Row 3 - 87  25  Kee
2. Now open the other Workbook - say Book2.xls. Select the cell in which you want to put the value. In that cell press "=" (the 'equals' sign)
3. Now this is the important bit. After pressing that 'equals' go back to the first excel workbook and select the cell, the content of which you want entered in the second workbook.

So, in this case, the cell in the second workbook will have a formula like this
=[Book1]Sheet1!$A$2

Do the same for the rest of the cells you want.

Important: Please note that the second workbook will not be filled unless the first workbook is opened also.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function: VLOOKUP

Comment: how would i do that? im not very advanced on excel

Comment: In Excel, press F1 then type VLOOKUP into the search box